# How do I keep my text below my image container so it doesn't get covered up?

Tags: html, css

My text keeps ending up behind my image container. How do I keep the text below the image? The text is not a caption for the images. I have pasted some code below and the project lives here as well https://github.com/sopperman89/New-Project. Any help is appreciated.

```
.image-container {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.image-container img {
  max-width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: multiple-image-crossfade;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 6s;
```

Comment: why are you using position: absolute? Try removing it.

Comment: @ThetAung if I remove the 'position: absolute' then the text does stay below where I want it but the image transition does not work properly.

Comment: Ok, I checked your repo. I see what you're trying to do. Now, my solution is don't remove position:abosolute. Instead, adding height: 150px; under that line. And remember, when you're using position absolute the element(in this case img) overflows the container, so, make sure to set it the same height as the container.

Comment: I just tried that out and it still doesn't keep the text below the image container. I think I need to try a different transition so I can change the position from absolute.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image-container {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
}
.image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: multiple-image-crossfade;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```